# Modify env.BRANCH_NAME variable with branch-env.BRANCH_NAME in jenkinsfile for a multibranch pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have created a multibranch pipeline project and thus created jenkinsfile and put that in dev branch. 
In one of the stage, I have to run mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.scm.branch=branch-${env.BRANCH_NAME} but it's giving error as bad substitution branch-${env.BRANCH_NAME}.
I  need branch-${env.BRANCH_NAME} as a branch-name  so that at sonar i can see branch-dev at branches section in sonar dashboard.

if i use  mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.scm.branch=env.BRANCH_NAME then it provides output but it will act as short-lived branch in sonar. but at sonar we want branch as long-lived branch.

## !/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
      agent { label 'ol73_slave-jdk8u192-git' }

```
options {
    timestamps()
    timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}

stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
              }
                      }





    stage('Unit Test and Code Scan') {
        steps {


          echo "*****JUnit Tests, JaCoCo Code Coverage, & SonarQube Code Qualiy Scan*****"
         withMaven(jdk: 'jdk8_u192', maven: 'maven-3.3.9', mavenSettingsConfig: '79ecf9bd-8cbc-4d5e-b7d1-200241e16b52') {

         sh '''


           cd DARC
             mvn clean package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=***** -Dsonar.login=******* -Dsonar.exclusions=file:**/src/test/** -B -Pcoverage -Dsonar.branch.name=branch-${env.BRANCH_NAME}

            ''' 

                              }



               }

                                      }




 }
```

}

Comment: what's branch name when you use : `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.scm.branch=env.BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: barnch name is dev     @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: so `dev` branch, you want to `dev` branch is long-lived branch on sonarqube? right ?

Answer (score 0):

In groovy Strings are encapsulated in single quotes `''` and GStrings in double quotes `""`

In order to do interpolation you need to be using GStrings. In your example, this should simply be

```
  sh """


       cd DARC
       mvn clean package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=***** -Dsonar.login=******* -Dsonar.exclusions=file:**/src/test/** -B -Pcoverage -Dsonar.branch.name=branch-${env.BRANCH_NAME}

     """
```

Comment: not able to fetch the value of ${env.BRANCH_NAME}.Even if i use sonar.scm.branch=${env.BRANCH_NAME} only.  Output is bad substitution. @metalisticpain